# Create bootable USB of Windows 8.1 on Mavericks 10.9.4

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb, windows

I've followed the instructions to enable the "Create windows 7 install Disk" in bootcamp but I am attempting to install Windows 8.1.  How do I force bootcamp to allow me to create a windows 7 or later install disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a version of Bootcamp AND Mac that explicitly supports Windows 8.1. Apple has a knowledge-base article that shows what O/S and Mac supports what version of Windows:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634

Unfortunately there are some Mac models that just won't support certain versions of Windows. Interestingly (or oddly..) enough the new MacPro and most (many?) of the new Macs **only** support windows 8.

Comment: Turns out my mid 2010 13" mbp does not support Windows 8. Solved problem by using my sister's late 2012 13" mbp. Thanks!